# SugarCRM error logging

Tags: logging, sugarcrm, error-logging, suitecrm

Is it possible to separate the log file where error logs are logged depending on their level.

For example I have `level = fatal`, I will put all the fatal logs to `sugarcrm_fatal.log`, `level = info`, I will put all the info logs to `sugarcrm_info.log`

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Interesting idea. Are you thinking of logging all simultaneously? If so, be aware of the amount of errors that can be generated at info or debug level, that can be a lot of disk writes which could potentially affect the applications performance.

Answer (score 0):

I did not do it myself you should try it i just refer the links.It may help you.

**Creating Custom Loggers**

**Custom Loggers**

Custom loggers can be used to write log entries to a centralized application management tool, or to write messages to a developer tool such as `FirePHP`.

To do this, you can create a new instance class that implements the `LoggerTemplate` interface. The below code is an example of how to create a `FirePHP` logger.

You will first need to create your logger class in `./custom/include/SugarLogger/`. For this example, we will create .`/custom/include/SugarLogger/FirePHPLogger.php`.

<

```
?php

// change the path below to the path to your FirePHP install
require_once('/path/to/fb.php');

class FirePHPLogger implements LoggerTemplate
{
    /** Constructor */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (
            isset($GLOBALS['sugar_config']['logger']['default'])
            && $GLOBALS['sugar_config']['logger']['default'] == 'FirePHP'
        )
        {
            LoggerManager::setLogger('default','FirePHPLogger');
        }
    }

    /** see LoggerTemplate::log() */
    public function log($level, $message)
    {
        // change to a string if there is just one entry
        if ( is_array($message) && count($message) == 1 )
        {
            $message = array_shift($message);
        }

        switch ($level)
        {
            case 'debug':
                FB::log($message);
                break;
            case 'info':
                FB::info($message);
                break;
            case 'deprecated':
            case 'warn':
                FB::warn($message);
                break;
            case 'error':
            case 'fatal':
            case 'security':
                FB::error($message);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The only method that needs to be implemented by default is the `log()` method, which writes the log message to the backend. You can specify which log levels this backend can use in the constuctor by calling the `LoggerManager::setLogger()` method and specifying the level to use for this logger in the first parameter; passing 'default' makes it the logger for all logging levels.

You will then specify your default logger as '`FirePHP`' in your `config_override.php` file.

```
$sugar_config['logger']['default'] = 'FirePHP';
```

[Refer Link](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Architecture/Logging/Creating_Custom_Loggers/index.html)

[More information about Logs](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.7/Architecture/Logging/)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one.

Comment: Tried this but this only triggers if you are debugging using FirePHP

Comment: I think only that much possible.